# Drools reuse a StatefulKnowledgeSession?

Tags: java, drools

I've got a problem where creating new drools StatefulKnowledgeSession instances is CPU intensive. There's an old nabble link that talks about it [here](http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/CPU-Spike-creating-a-StatefulKnowledgeSession-using-OSGi-td1053579.html). I'm not sure how I'd work around it, so I figured I'd create a pool of them. So far, I'm completely unable to find out if they are reusable or not. I know they aren't multithread safe in the sense of having 2 threads running rules at the same time, but can I reuse a session in a new thread later down the line after the last usage has called dispose()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating a single KnowledgeSessionConfiguration and reusing that with every creation of a KnowledgeSession. For whatever reason (apparently a large classpath), creating the configuration was extremely expensive for me, just like the article I linked. I'm not sure what I lose by creating the KnowledgeSessionConfiguration just once and reusing it. Everything seems to be behaving normally.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the knowledge base in a separate context, then creating a statefulKnowledgeSessions is not expensive. You only need to avoid compiling the rules every time that you need a session (builder.add()). You can create a new session per request and dispose it to avoid memory leaks, I think that you will be fine creating sessions instead of trying to reuse them.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was creating a rule engine application using Drools. I came across similar situation.

I ended up using a **KieSession pool** based out of **Apache GenericObjectPool** interface. All you need is to give a way to create and destroy the KieSession object.

Using pool either you can return the borrowed KieSession object back to Pool or simply **invalidate** it (which in turn will **dispose** and hence release memory). Simply returning it to Pool wont solve the problem as the KieSession working memory is **dirty** after the rule firing. Also simply deleting fact handles wont solve it because there are lot more objects like (*agenda, globalResolver, kieBaseEventListeners, ruleRuntimeEventSupport, defaultEntryPoint, timerService, initialFactHandle*) are referenced by KieSession which are also dirty.

Fortunately **StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl** provide a function to reset KieSession which in turn restores all these object and make it like **newly created KieSession**. You need to compare it yourself which one is more costly for you, simple creating a new one or reseting existing one.
Another aspect is after using KieSession as Pool you wont exactly need to create the sessions on the go if pool is configured with **optimum minIdle** value which will always make sure that **minimum KieSessions** object are always in the pool and hence there wont be any need of creating Session Objects while executing rules.